# One Apple ID Required for iPhone and iPad

Tags: ipad, iphone

My husband and I share a computer. We both have our own iPhone, mine a 4S and his a 3S. My husband also has a new iPad.

The problem: when I set up his new iPad it would not accept the Apple ID used on his iPhone, therefore I had to create another Apple ID for the iPad. Can one not have a single Apple ID and password for both devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same Apple ID on up to five devices.

I would reset the iPad and begin from scratch. I recently came across a similar problem with a new iPad and resetting it worked perfectly.

Comment: You can even use the same Apple ID for more than five devices (e.g. to access iCloud services).